# Help Needed for Inequality Proof

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $x>1$, then $\frac{1}{x}< \ln x - \ln(x-1)< \frac{1}{x-1}$. I tried splitting it into two parts and letting $f(x)= \ln x-\ln(x-1)-\frac{1}{x}$ and $g(x) = \ln x-\ln(x-1)-\frac{1}{x-1}$ and then trying to apply the mean value theorem for $(2,x)$, but it does not seem to workout. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can use mean value theorem

Comment: How would you go about applying it?

Answer (score 2):

$$
\ln(x)-\ln(x-1)=\int_{x-1}^x \frac 1 u \, du > \int_{x-1}^x \frac 1 x \,du = \frac 1 x. 
$$

Alternatively:
$$
\text{For some $c$ between $x-1$ and $x$, } \frac{\ln x - \ln(x-1)}{x-(x-1)} = \ln'(c) = \frac 1 c > \frac 1 x.
$$

Comment: I cannot use integration.

Comment: @g22 : So you can use the second method in my answer --- the mean value theorem.

Comment: Thanks. Now does that complete the proof for the left side of the inequality?

Comment: You can do the other inequality the same way, i.e. instead of $\frac1c>\frac1x$, write $\frac1c<\frac{1}{x-1}$. ${}\qquad{}$

Comment: Yes. ${{{{{}}}}}$

Comment: And that completes the proof?

Comment: Yes.  Of course you should write out in complete sentences an explanation of how the mean value theorem is being applied.

Answer (score 0):

*Hint*

Accroding to the Mean Value theorm there exists a $c$ between $x-1$ and $x$ such that:

$$\frac{1}{c}=\frac{\ln(x)-\ln(x-1)}{1}$$

Also note that $\frac{1}{x}$ is decreasing. ($\frac{1}{x}$ is derivative of $\ln(x)$)